# Show photos on click (facebook-style) form

Tags: photo

I need help on showing photos larger when you click them.
Let me explain better.

I am doing an art project. I am using MVC(model-view-controller) on CodeIgniter and I want ,if it is possible to show me the code,and where to put it...so when I click on the image it becomes larger,like the photos on facebook...they are small but when u click on them they became larger so you can better see the image.

Any idea ?

Would be appreciated :)

Comment: You're probably going to get flamed for this question since it has nothing to do with mvc or codeigniter. jQuery can handle the event easily but as for how you choose to implement it, it's pretty much basic html / js. If this question doesn't get closed soon I'll post an answer. In the meantime I suggest you edit it and remove those tags then show that you've tried something before posting here.

Comment: Thanks Kai :) I edited this...and I am waiting for your answer :) TY

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Ok here's the js fiddle:

http://jsfiddle.net/tK6up/2/

and here's the code. It assumes you're using the latest jQuery library:
HTML:

```
<img class="small_img" src="http://www.fleces.com/media/images/fleces_logo.png" style="width:100px;" />
<div id="large">

</div>
```

CSS:

```
#large{
    display:none; 
    position:absolute; 
    z-index:100; 
    top:10%; 
    left:10%;
}

.small_img{
    width:100px;
}
```

jQuery:

```
$(document).ready(function(){    
    $('.small_img').on('click', function(){
       $('#large').html($(this).clone().removeClass('small_img')).fadeIn("medium");
    });

    $('#large').on('click', function(){
        $(this).fadeOut("medium");   
    });
});
```

Keep in mind I just threw this together. I don't know what facebook does since I don't use that site. I just went by your description. In reality you might use lightbox to handle the popup and almost certainly you would re-style the css to fit your needs. But, as per your outline, this will work.